# Can't establish connection SQL Server using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Python to upload from a Pandas dataframe to a SQL Server table, but I can't successfully create a connection using sqlalchemy. I understand I first need to create an engine object using create_engine(), and create a connection object using engine.connect(), but no string I enter in create_engine() seems to work. I've tried the following:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://myServer/myDB')
conn = engine.connect()
```

and:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Server=myServer;Database=myDB;')
conn = engine.connect()
```

and:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
conn = engine.connect()
```

but all result in the following error:

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I've also tried:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
conn = engine.connect()
```

which results in the following error:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name too long (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

While I can successfully connect using pyodbc like this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

I can't seem to make this work for sqlalchemy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The solution:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://ERRSTSDBP2/ActPri?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
```

Thanks to norbeq for getting me most of the way there!

Answer (score 1):

You can try connection like this:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@host:port/myDB')
conn = engine.connect()
```

Comment: I don't have a password, I connect with Windows authentication. What does 'host:port' mean? I tried the following, it didn't work:

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://login@myServer/myDB')
conn = engine.connect()

Comment: Ok, so engine should be : `engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@myServer/myDB?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQLServer+Native+Client+11.0')`

Comment: Still getting this error:

InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: I got it!  The solution:

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://myServer/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')